# Nvidia PRIME Render Offload - Nvidia by default but some windows using Intel?

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-prime

I'm using Kubuntu 19.10 with Nvidia binary driver 440.48.02. I have the following GPU hardware:

- Intel UHD 630 ("iGPU")
- Internal dedicated GPU in laptop: RTX 2080 Max-Q ("dGPU")
- External GPU via Thunderbolt 3: RTX 2080 Ti ("eGPU")

My primary and only display is a 5120x1440 120Hz display attached to the eGPU via DisplayPort. The laptop has a display panel that is turned off.

I have the PRIME profile set to "on-demand", but all Vulkan and OpenGL contexts default to the eGPU. That's fine.

What I want is to be able to force certain windows to render on the Intel iGPU, or ideally, even the dGPU. So far I have not had any luck by trying to use the `prime-*` commands or `xrandr --setprovideroffloadsink`.

The purpose of offloading to the other GPUs is because certain windows that fully utilize the eGPU (e.g. a Vulkan game) can cause other windows rendered on the eGPU to have very, very poor performance. So it would be good to be able to offload and make use of all my graphics hardware.

```
$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 3
Provider 0: id: 0x1b8 cap: 0x0 crtcs: 4 outputs: 6 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-0
Provider 1: id: 0x384 cap: 0x0 crtcs: 0 outputs: 0 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-G1
Provider 2: id: 0x209 cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 3 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
```

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (and flavors like Kubuntu) will be released in 2020-April, and will be on-topic then, and until then development releases or ubuntu+1 are off-topic on this site. You'll need to be very patient, or seek help on a site that allows ubuntu+1 (IRC, Ubuntu Forums etc), or if it is a problem/bug - please report it.  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Comment: Edited the OP to say 19.10. Can I get help now? (The problem is exactly, 100% identical on 19.10 vs. the current development 20.04, and I can easily test any solution in 19.10 because I have a zfs snapshot of my 19.10 system pre-upgrade, so any answers I will test on 19.10.)

Comment: Voted to leave open. Concerned downvoters should retract their downvotes.